# GKE node pool tags and firewall rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, firewall, gke-networking

I have a GCP project with:

- VPC:

  - `subnet0`: cidr `10.1.0.0/24`
  - `subnet1`: cidr `10.2.0.0/24`
- GKE cluster in the `subnet0` subnet and:

  - pods cidr: `172.16.0.0/18`
  - service cidr: `172.16.64.0/20`
  - node pool tags: `gke-pool`
- a VM instance in the `subnet1` subnet and tags `agent`

I would like to create a firewall rules that would allow pods in the GKE cluster to connect to the VM, so I have created the following firewall rule:

- `network`: `VPC`
- `direction`: `INGRESS`
- source tags: `gke-pool`
- target tags: `agent`
- port: 80/tcp

But it does not work.

Instead if I set the source range to the pods cidr (`172.16.0.0/18`) it works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using a [VPC Native Cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alias-ips). VPC Native clusters are the default mode and they made the Pod IP's visible in the VPC. This means  when a pod talks to a destination which is on VPC, the IP of the Pod is NOT Source Nated behind the Node IP.

You have two options:

- Use the Pod CIDR in your firewall rule as you mentionned.
- Use the [IP masq Agent](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent) to hide the Pod IP's behind the Node IP's.